# Is a work performance appraisal a good time to bring up concerns about job role?

Tags: new-job, productivity, complaint, appraisal

**BACKGROUND**

I work within an IT organisation and have done for a number of years. I started at this company since I finished University so I am well ingrained within the department. My roles have all been technical, and those roles have adapted and grown the more I've learned during my years here.

I was at a point where I felt I was experiencing a knowledge cap. The work I was originally doing (although technical) was becoming far too easy and I wanted a new challenge. Internally, a role became available which was heavily technical, and the team advertising specifically asked me to join. In theory this was a win/win for both parties.

Once I had started the new role, the first month or 2 were based around learning the new technologies, with an aim on creating a few fixes and implementing them in our environment. However, I am now a number of months into this job and I have been tasked with a very administrative task, i.e. filling out data on a spreadsheet. This had never been mentioned at any stage during the job discussions or in the job description. I have the tag of "XXXX will get this fixed/completed properly" so give him this work.

I would understand the assignment of this task if I had been under-performing, but I have learned the new technologies, implemented a number of fixes, and generally suggested numerous ideas on how we can improve the workflow.

I have mentioned to my manager that this work should be done by a member of the team running the project day to day. Which it appeared they agreed.

Although it's difficult to put into words, there is a large amount of admin work that needs to be done. So much so that I'm unable to complete many of the other tasks I was originally employed to do. I have been offered no additional help to do this because no one wants to do it.

As I am only a few months in the role, I feel as if I don't have much of a platform to complain.

My performance appraisal is with my managers manager. Is this an appropriate time to raise my concerns about what was discuss compared to what's being delivered? I've never really had a proper appraisal before so I'm unsure, but I don't want my career to stagnate and would rather return to my old team if this is the work I will be doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formal annual performance appraisal is never a good place to bring up any new topic.

In some cases, it may be the only place – but that doesn't make it good.

Ideally, you'll have regular opportunities to discuss such matters with your manager, and you should be bringing it up – informally – as soon as it starts preying on your mind. And your manager should return the favour, discussing performance concerns with you long before you a formal meeting.

If you don't have regular meetings with your manager where you could discuss this, then you should ideally make an opportunity. Book a meeting of your own if needed. This way, you're driving the agenda, and you can make sure your concerns get proper consideration, rather than having them disappear in amongst all the other things that crop up during a formal review.

Comment: Thanks Bill! Luckily enough it was something that was already on the agenda for the appraisal. I have also raised the idea of having biweekly meetings to discuss any issues. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other 1-1 chats coming up with your manager (and the appraisal is relatively soon) then it makes sense - in most companies an annual appraisal should be a two-way process and it's a valid place to bring up any questions or concerns you have about the duties of the role going forward. I would try and make it about the *future* rather than the past as in my opinion it will come across better.

That said however (and I appreciate this wasn't the main thrust of your question) I do wonder if you're overthinking this. Many jobs require you to perform a non-trivial amount of admin that is distinct from the actual "production" part of the job and because they are fairly mundane I wouldn't expect them to be explicitly discussed at an interview or in a job description. You seem to be taking the assignment of this task as some kind of unspoken critiscim of your performance but I'm not getting that read - admin tasks certainly aren't glamorous but that doesn't mean they don't need doing and

> I have the tag of "XXXX will get this fixed/completed properly" so give him this work.

Actually reads to me that this task needs doing and **you** are the person they trust to get it done and to get it done right. Which actually suggests that they think highly of you!

If the admin tasks are causing you to struggle to meet deadlines or milestones on your other tasks then discuss this with your manager in the same way you would the balancing of any other competing tasks - if you can't determine which task is a higher priority yourself then ask your manager (or whomever assigns your tasks) which they would prefer you to prioritize and make any knock-on effects to deadlines clear.

Comment: Hi motosubatsu. Thank you for the advice. I'm a bit surprised that this got downvoted because I found this genuienly useful advice. I appreciate the help. The "overthinking" comments are definitely applicable to me, and something I will refer to later on if this situation occurs again. (Which I thankfully have been told won't).

Comment: @Qwerty123 such is the mystery of SE.. The important thing to me is that it was useful for you. Glad it all went well with the appraisal :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way for you to schedule a 1 on 1 with your manager?

In some companies you can request the meeting to discuss work stuff

If yes, put in subject  position / productivity discussion.

But i would wait until the performance review is complete to schedule it
Let us know how it will turn out

Comment: Hi Strader, as mentioned in my comment to Bill. We should now be having biweekly meetings to discuss internal team issues and problems should they arise. The appraisal turned out well, and, I was explained as to why I was set the task, and apologised to for having to do it! All parties happy in the end :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Amazing. Good luck